# Need to parse unfiltered url querys via PHP, can't deal with '&' signs

Tags: php, string, url

first of all: I'm not a professional php developer, I'm just able to scramble together a few bits of code to make basic stuff work.

I also don't know how to properly name all that stuff, so let me give you some background:

A client of ours wants to send an email containing a link to a vcard qr-code, that contains contact details of their clients to every client they have (between 100-5000 clients possibly).
They don't want to do this by hand so they asked me for an automation solution.

They have a marketing tool that allows them to send mass emails containing the customers details.
So entering 'Hello %name%' in the emails text will be replaced with each customers name in their respective email.

So I found an api that does what they need, it takes url query strings to generate a vcard qr-code (as png file).
I made a script that takes custom query strings, some of them are being sent to said api, some of them are just being embed on the page, so people can print the qr-code including some extra information they need.

The whole system will be used as a "entry-ticket-system" for an event they are hosting, that being said, no high requirements, those tickets are free, our customer wants to use the v-card qr code so they can scan the "tickets" on entry and verify who was actually there, to target them with marketing campaigns later on.

Now to get to the technical part:

This is the api we are using:
https://qrcode.tec-it.com/en/VCard
The way we are currently using it, is by displaying the qr-code in html (`<img src="https://qrcode.tec-it.com/API/QRCode?data=BEGIN%3aVCARD%0d%0aVERSION%3a2.1%0d%0aN%3aJohn+Doe%0d%0aTEL%3bHOME%3bVOICE%3a555-555-5555%0d%0aTEL%3bWORK%3bVOICE%3a666-666-6666%0d%0aEMAIL%3aemail%40example.com%0d%0aORG%3aTEC-IT%0d%0aURL%3ahttps%3a%2f%2fwww.example.com%0d%0aEND%3aVCARD&backcolor=%23ffffff" />`) and then entering the url query strings as a variable.

This looks something like this:

```
$fname = filter_var($_GET['fname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$lname = filter_var($_GET['lname'], FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
$email = filter_var($_GET['email'], FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
$fullname = $fname . ' ' . $lname;

echo '<br><img src="https://qrcode.tec-it.com/API/QRCode?data=BEGIN%3aVCARD%0d%0aVERSION%3a2.1%0d%0aN%3a'.$fullname.'%0d%0aEMAIL%3a'.$email. (...)
```

Now we come to the problem: The email service our customer is using is only able to fill in basic strings, which we cannot modify. So if a client's email would theoretically contain a '&' sign, it would break up the url by indicating a new url query string. We cannot encode them, nor can we do http push.
We can't properly access the data either, we could only export everyting into a csv, modify them and re-import all of their customers (last solution)

Is there any solution for this, so we can accept basically any character within the url. A friend of mine suggested to use a json in the url, however json just has different characters that would break everything.
Everything else does work fine, it's just the '&' sign I'm currently aware of.

PS: I do know that the php code isn't proper code, very low quality. This is okay, the customer is aware of that, they just wanted the cheapest possible solution so they don't have to do it by hand, they have been informed about possible bugs and the very much existing security flaws.

I hope someone can give me a push in the right direction, how could one possibly handle this?

Thanks in advance and apologies for low quality code and possibly unclear explanations, I'm trying my best.

Comment: There's nothing you can do if they don't urlencode data that they put in a URL.

Comment: The normal way would be to send only a unique identifier (and a security hash, perhaps) rather than sending all the customer details as you are. The server that your qrcode points to then handles translating that UID into the actual customer details, and it's more secure than putting the actual details in the qrcode (what's to stop a customer making their own to mess with your client's data?). Or use a different email service, of course - if it's the client's choice of mail service, and it prevents them from doing something they want to do, choosing a different one must surely be an option?

Comment: If you need to use it in your URL that you show in the echo, then you need to `urlencode` the email or use `FILTER_SANITIZE_ENCODED`.  You should do that for all vars you put in the URL.

Comment: I'm not entirely clear on the workflow here. Where does your script come in? If your script is the one producing the URLs why can't you just `urlencode()` the name and email address?

Comment: Thank you, that's all I needed to here, we will simply remove the one field where the '&' sign can be entered (company's name). No more responses needed.